# Proper way to use results of a post request to update a webpage

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-chrome-extension, web-applications

I'm new to web development and trying to properly update a popup I create after a post request.  The way I am doing it seems far too convoluted.
Basically I have a chrome extension that at a certain point makes a post request to my database and comes back with a url.  I then want to open up a popup and have the url my database just delivered in the popup.  It seems simple and I am sure my current design is over complicating it:
In **content.js** I invoke the function doWork:

```
function doWork(itemName, itemPrice) {

    var items = [{'itemName': itemName, 'price': itemPrice}]
    // ajax the JSON to the server
    $.post('https:my/url/receiver', JSON.stringify(items), 
        function(data, status){
            chrome.runtime.sendMessage({type:'open_deals_page', url:data.url})
        });
}
```

This is received by **background.js** in the following function:

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
    if (request.type === 'open_deals_page') {
        chrome.tabs.create({
            url: chrome.extension.getURL('popup.html'),
            active: false
        }, function(tab) {
                chrome.windows.create({
                tabId: tab.id,
                type: 'panel',
                height: 200, width:200,
                focused: true,
                // incognito, top, left, ...
            });
            adjust_window(request.url)
        });
    }
});
```

after which in an ideal world, the function adjust_window would change the 
html element with id='itemUrl' in the popup.html below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html><html><head><title>Dialog test</title></head><body>
</title>There is a better deal elsewhere on the web @</title>
<a href="giggle.com" id='itemUrl'>the url you requested</a>
</html>
```

needless to say, I am not sure how to set up the adjust_window function or whether I am invoking it in the proper location. I tried various jquery selectors and kept getting null values.  I am also getting confused about how to make sure I access the specific popup I just opened. thanks!

Comment: Modern Chrome disallows cross-origin requests in content scripts. Do it in the background script and use messaging for coordination.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it  necessary to make the web request from `content.js`? This seems like something that could happen in the background. If the issue is access to jQuery (for `$.post`), then I'd recommend checking out the native `fetch` function. For you it would look something like

```
fetch(
  'https://your/url/receiver', 
  { 
    method: 'POST', 
    body: JSON.stringify(items)
  }
).then(res => res.json()).then(data => data.url)
```

The above uses "arrow function expressions", but if those are making it harder to understand, the below is equivalent!

```
fetch(
  'https://your/url/receiver', 
  { 
    method: 'POST', 
    body: JSON.stringify(items)
  }
).then(function(res) { return res.json() }).then(function(data) { return data.url })
```

Comment: in the promises I see you have the variables res and data--where and how ought I to define them?  that's tripping me up.  with regards to the request being in **content.js** there is no particular reason, so I moved them to **background.js**

Comment: @NoahFriedman gotcha! `res` and `data` are both defined as arguments in an "arrow func" I suspect  the arrow func syntax is throwing you off, so I added an example that doesn't use them. Let me know if that helps!